# Github : Create a new project from existing project for EXOplayer

Tags: github

I want to create a new my own project from an existing project such as EXOplayer of Android: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

What should I do for this purpose?
Is there any concern to directly copy all from the repository and upload to become a new project?

I am a rookie for it so have no idea about what should I start.

Thanks

Comment: You need to create fork of this repository http://i.imgur.com/Z2wwIvA.png

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean Fork a repo? Basically you copy the entire project to your github, so you freely can make changes.
Read: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

Go to the project gihub link and locate the Fork :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If would you like to someone else project of your own,This process is known a **forking**.

Create a fork is producing a personal copy of someone else project.You can submit a **Pull request** to help other project make better by your changes which offering a changes up to other project.

Go through this link have more in detail [Github guildlines](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to make a copy of the project in GitHub, follow the process mentioned herein by creating a fork:  https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

However, if you are looking to make a local copy, you want to Clone the repository: https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/